# Run DLL on Azure Cloud Service

Tags: node.js, azure, dll, cloud, webrole

I've worked a lot with Azure websites but not cloud services. I need to spin up a cloud service that uses a third party dll to generate pdfs (http://wkhtmltopdf.org/). However, I would like to write this server in nodejs and almost all examples are in asp.net. I just need to know how to reference and execute this dll (or exe, if that's easier) from node js in an Azure Web Role when a request comes in. I'd greatly appreciate any pointers.

Thanks,
Sam

**EDIT:** It's not necessarily a matter of referencing or using the dll from the code that I will have an issue with. It's how to INSTALL the dll on an Azure web role. All you can do in an Azure cloud service / web role is upload the project package but no explanation on how to add a dll or exe (except in asp.net, which I am not using. I'm using nodejs).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put the installer in your web role package, and set up a startup task in the ServiceDefinition.csdef file for the roles.
Here is the sample on official site [Install .NET on a Cloud Service Role](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/cloud-services-dotnet-install-dotnet/), which is guiding to install .NET in Cloud service, the steps and scenario should be the same.

Comment: Thanks Gary. Marking this as the answer. However, I should note that with wkhtmltopdf the script would freeze at the install line. I found out that I just needed to extract the installer, and then I didn't need to install it on the server at all. I just put the contents in the server folder and executed the exe using a node child process. Either way, this answer is definitely the path to take if you do need to install something.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of wrappers for [wkhtmltopdf](https://www.npmjs.com/search?q=wkhtmltopdf). [This one is nice and pipable](https://www.npmjs.com/package/wkhtmltopdf) (you can stream the output directly to your client):

```
var wkhtmltopdf = require('wkhtmltopdf');

// URL 
wkhtmltopdf('http://google.com/', { pageSize: 'letter' })
  .pipe(fs.createWriteStream('out.pdf'));

// HTML 
wkhtmltopdf('<h1>Test</h1><p>Hello world</p>')
  .pipe(res);
```

You have to install wkhtmltopdf (the command line tool) first of course.

Comment: I am already aware of this library. This will not work on an Azure website because you cannot install the command line tool to begin with. I need to know how to install the command line tool on an Azure cloud service (web role), hence my question. :)

Comment: Yes, your question was not that at all and thus it has nothing to do with nodejs :p Something that can help: https://www.simple-talk.com/cloud/platform-as-a-service/installing-third-party-software-on-windows-azure-%E2%80%93-what-are-the-options/ The 2nd technique (Startup Task) should work very well.

Comment: Thanks for that. I'll try it out and if it works I'll post the answer (or you can if you like).

Comment: Sadly it doesn't work. Even trying to install the default ReportViewer.exe in the example never installs it. :( I know because I logged into my cloud service and it's not installed on the system.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the dll is a managed assembly (i.e. an assembly compiled using .net), you can use [edge.js](http://tjanczuk.github.io/edge/) to get NodeJS to interact with the dll.

If it is an exe, you can execute the process via NodeJS's asynchronous process creation API.

Comment: Perhaps I didn't explain the question very well. It's not necessarily a matter of referencing or using the dll from the code that I will have an issue with. It's how to INSTALL the dll on an Azure web role. All you can do in an Azure cloud service / web role is upload the project package but no explanation on how to add a dll or exe (except in asp.net, which I am not using. I'm using nodejs).

Comment: You can add the dll as part of your project package.

Comment: That's exactly what I'd like to know how to do. :) In a nodejs project.

Comment: This should be as simple as copying the dll into the solution project, whether in Visual Studio or otherwise.